# RegEx for matching whitespace OR punctuations AND non-alphanumerics

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have this regex:

`(\s+)|([.,!?:;'\"\'-])`

This is matching against any space(s) or punctuation in the array but not all punctuation and I'm struggling to find an example of something that matches any punctuation.

I thought about matching against where the character is not alpha-numeric however this is causing issues with accented letters and different lexicons.

Is there any all-inclusive for punctuation such as (**when I say punctuation I wish to include symbols**):

> `,.#@

etc.

Comment: this is a comprehensive guide. follow it and you will be able to build it yourself :p https://itnext.io/regular-expressions-tricks-you-should-know-2976c7bd1be3

Comment: Just include additional characters in you character class.

Comment: See [Supported Unicode General Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories) and Supported Named Blocks below.

Comment: You may need to do text normalization first. See [String.Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.8) method. Also see [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), [Normalization FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use `[\p{P}\p{S}]`:

```
(\s+)|([\p{P}\p{S}])
```

`[\p{P}\p{S}]` will match any character that is a punctuation or a symbol char.

See the [list of subproperties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property) these classes refer to:

#### Punctuation

| Property | Meanings | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pc | Punctuation, connector | Includes "_" underscore |
| Pd | Punctuation, dash | Includes several hyphen characters |
| Ps | Punctuation, open | Opening bracket characters |
| Pe | Punctuation, close | Closing bracket characters |
| Pi | Punctuation, initial quote | Opening quotation mark. Does not include the ASCII "neutral" quotation mark. May behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage |
| Pf | Punctuation, final quote | Closing quotation mark. May behave like Ps or Pe depending on usage |
| Po | Punctuation, other |  |

#### Symbol

| Property | Meanings | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sm | Symbol, math | [Mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) (e.g., +, −, =, ×, ÷, √, ∊). Does not include parentheses and brackets, which are in categories Ps and Pe. Also does not include !, *, -, or /, which despite frequent use as mathematical operators, are primarily considered to be "punctuation". |
| Sc | Symbol, currency | [Currency symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol) |
| Sk | Symbol, modifier |  |
| So | Symbol, other |  |

Answer (score 2):

if matching an underscore is not necesary you could use

> \W

instead of what you are currently using it will match any character that is not number, letter or underscore.

Comment: This doesn't work because of accented characters / different lexicons e.g `é`

Comment: I tried it in regex storm before sending this to you, that character is not detected, do you want it detected then?

Comment: It is as I'm using it and is according to `regexr`

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cW&i=%c3%a9.fasfsaf.-%c3%a1%c3%a4 check that link im not seeing what you say